# phpexcel insert qrcode into excel and save it to client end

Tags: php, phpexcel, qr-code

I was trying to export data to excel file with a `QRcode` within a cell.
I googled up and tried for clue.

Finally thought with adding a sample image file. then after with a `phpqrcode` image file.

It is still not succeeded can you please help me out.

Code:

```
/** Error reporting */
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', TRUE);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', TRUE);
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');

if (PHP_SAPI == 'cli')
    die('This example should only be run from a Web Browser');

/** Include PHPExcel */
require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/Classes/PHPExcel.php';


// Create new PHPExcel object
$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();

$gdImage = imagecreatefromjpeg('abstract_bg.jpg');
 //Add a drawing to the worksheet
 echo date('H:i:s') . " Add a drawing to the worksheet\n";
$objDrawing = new PHPExcel_Worksheet_MemoryDrawing();
$objDrawing->setName('Sample image');$objDrawing->setDescription('Sample image');
$objDrawing->setImageResource($gdImage);
$objDrawing->setRenderingFunction(PHPExcel_Worksheet_MemoryDrawing::RENDERING_JPEG);
$objDrawing->setMimeType(PHPExcel_Worksheet_MemoryDrawing::MIMETYPE_DEFAULT);
$objDrawing->setHeight(150);
$objDrawing->setWorksheet($objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet());
//$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');$objWriter->save(str_replace('.php', '.xlsx', __FILE__));

// Set document properties
$objPHPExcel->getProperties()->setCreator("Jimson Jose")
                             ->setLastModifiedBy("Jimson Jose")
                             ->setTitle("Office 2007 XLSX Test Document")
                             ->setSubject("Office 2007 XLSX Test Document")
                             ->setDescription("For minimizing work force by jimson, generated using PHP classes.")
                             ->setKeywords("office 2007 openxml php")
                             ->setCategory("Rewards");


// Add some data
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
            ->setCellValue('A1', 'Hello')
            ->setCellValue('B2', 'world!')
            ->setCellValue('C1', 'Hello')
            ->setCellValue('D2', 'world!');

// Miscellaneous glyphs, UTF-8
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
            ->setCellValue('A4', 'Miscellaneous glyphs')
            ->setCellValue('A5', 'éàèùâêîôûëïüÿäöüç');

// Rename worksheet
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setTitle('Simple');


// Set active sheet index to the first sheet, so Excel opens this as the first sheet
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);


// Redirect output to a client’s web browser (Excel2007)
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="01simple.xlsx"');
header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
// If you're serving to IE 9, then the following may be needed
header('Cache-Control: max-age=1');

// If you're serving to IE over SSL, then the following may be needed
header ('Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT'); // Date in the past
header ('Last-Modified: '.gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s').' GMT'); // always modified
header ('Cache-Control: cache, must-revalidate'); // HTTP/1.1
header ('Pragma: public'); // HTTP/1.0

$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');
$objWriter->save('php://output');
exit;
?>
```

Comment: Any errors or simply your image isn't shown?

Comment: No errors displayed/observed, but file is unable to be opened after it is downloaded.

Comment: One missing thing is that you should insert image into a cell `$objDrawing->setCoordinates('E1');`

Comment: Forgot to add the same, but still issues remains the same.

Comment: Sorry Gennadiy i was on a holiday with my family,, today i modified the code, your code works fine thank you..

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When generating a file, you should make no debug output like

```
echo date('H:i:s') . " Add a drawing to the worksheet\n";
```

because it corrupts binary output.

If you remove this line, your code will work.

```
<?php
/** Error reporting */
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', TRUE);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', TRUE);
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');

if (PHP_SAPI == 'cli')
    die('This example should only be run from a Web Browser');

/** Include PHPExcel */
require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/Classes/PHPExcel.php';


// Create new PHPExcel object
$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();

$gdImage = imagecreatefromjpeg('abstract_bg.jpg');
 //Add a drawing to the worksheet

$objDrawing = new PHPExcel_Worksheet_MemoryDrawing();
$objDrawing->setName('Sample image');$objDrawing->setDescription('Sample image');
$objDrawing->setImageResource($gdImage);
$objDrawing->setRenderingFunction(PHPExcel_Worksheet_MemoryDrawing::RENDERING_JPEG);
$objDrawing->setMimeType(PHPExcel_Worksheet_MemoryDrawing::MIMETYPE_DEFAULT);
$objDrawing->setHeight(150);
$objDrawing->setWorksheet($objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet());
//$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');$objWriter->save(str_replace('.php', '.xlsx', __FILE__));

// Set document properties
$objPHPExcel->getProperties()->setCreator("Jimson Jose")
                             ->setLastModifiedBy("Jimson Jose")
                             ->setTitle("Office 2007 XLSX Test Document")
                             ->setSubject("Office 2007 XLSX Test Document")
                             ->setDescription("For minimizing work force by jimson, generated using PHP classes.")
                             ->setKeywords("office 2007 openxml php")
                             ->setCategory("Rewards");


// Add some data
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
            ->setCellValue('A1', 'Hello')
            ->setCellValue('B2', 'world!')
            ->setCellValue('C1', 'Hello')
            ->setCellValue('D2', 'world!');

// Miscellaneous glyphs, UTF-8
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
            ->setCellValue('A4', 'Miscellaneous glyphs')
            ->setCellValue('A5', 'éàèùâêîôûëïüÿäöüç');

// Rename worksheet
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setTitle('Simple');


// Set active sheet index to the first sheet, so Excel opens this as the first sheet
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);


// Redirect output to a client’s web browser (Excel2007)
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="01simple.xlsx"');
header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
// If you're serving to IE 9, then the following may be needed
header('Cache-Control: max-age=1');

// If you're serving to IE over SSL, then the following may be needed
header ('Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT'); // Date in the past
header ('Last-Modified: '.gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s').' GMT'); // always modified
header ('Cache-Control: cache, must-revalidate'); // HTTP/1.1
header ('Pragma: public'); // HTTP/1.0

$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');
$objWriter->save('php://output');
exit;
?>
```

I would also recommend removing error reporting from this script:

```
/** Error reporting */
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', TRUE);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', TRUE);
```

Comment: This is true when, as in this example, you output the file to php://output; If xls file is saved to disk debug information can be present